# T-SQL - Joining NVARCHAR field that may contain UNIQUEIDENTIFIER or STRING

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a field in one of my tables that may contain a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER or a string representing a name.  I want to use this field to join to another table where if the value is a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER it should join with the KEY field of the second table, but if the value is a string it should join with the NAME field of the second table.

Here is an example of my query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 AS T2
    ON
        T2.NAME = T1.NAME
        OR T2.KEY = T1.NAME
```

This query doesn't work because it throws an error when trying to convert a string to a UNIQUEIDENTIFER.  Unfortunately, I don't have another field that would identify which records contain UNIQUEIDENTIFIERs vs strings in order to simply perform 2 queries and UNION them.

Does anyone know the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try converting the UID to a string type and matching that?

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    Table1 AS T1
     LEFT JOIN 
    Table2 AS T2ON
        CAST(T2.KEY AS NVARCHAR(50)) = T1.NAME OR
        T2.NAME = T1.NAME
```